# Does $\infty^0=1$?

Tags: exponentiation, infinity

I was wondering if $\infty^0=1$. Some people have told me that there is no answer; it is undefined. Others have told me that the answer is $1$, using the rule $a^0=1, \ a\neq 0$. If it is truly undefined, then why is it undefined? Please answer, thanks!

Comment: The expression $\infty^0$ is utterly meaningless: $\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: $+\infty$ is an extended real number. $(+\infty)^0$ is still meaningless under that interpretation. $+\infty$ is also a limit form. $(+\infty)^0$ is an indeterminate limit form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\infty^0=\infty^{^\frac1\infty}=\sqrt[\infty]\infty$ . Now, $\sqrt[n]x$ is the quantity which, when multiplied *n* times with itself, gives *x*. So: which quantity, multiplied an infinite number of times with itself, yield infinity as a result ? Obviously, **any** real number $>1$ has this property, as well as infinity itself. So the result is rightly left undefined, since it is **not unique**. Or, better said, it is an entire interval (as opposed to a single value), namely $(1,\infty]$.

Comment: A number near $0$ can be negative. Even if we restrict attention to positives, $x^{1/x}$ has limit $1$ as $x\to\infty$. And let $f(x)=2^x$ when $x$ is even, $3^x$ when $x$ is odd. Then $(f(x))^{1/x}$ does not have a limi.

Comment: @JChau: Generally speaking, you can post comments and requests for clarification when people answer and you're not sure what to make of those answers. This comment of yours shows lack of effort to try and accommodate the efforts of other people to help you.

Answer (score 6):

Since $\infty$ is not a real number, the expression $\infty^0$ is not interpreted like $3^0$, but rather as the following:

> We are given two sequences of real numbers, $a_n$ and $b_n$, such that $\lim a_n=0$ and $\lim b_n=\infty$, and now we calculate the limit of the exponentiation, $\lim b_n^{a_n}$.

If $a_n=0$ for all $n$, then the limit will be $1$, because $b_n^0=1$ (recall that $b_n$ *is* a real number).

If $a_n$ is not identically $0$ for all sufficiently large $n$, then this will require a closer analysis of the terms $b_n^{a_n}$, and the rates in which they converge to their respective limits. Some examples:

1. $a_n=\frac1n$ and $b_n=n^n$, in this case $b_n^{a_n}=n$, so $\infty^0$ becomes $\infty$.
2. $a_n=-\frac1n$ and $b_n=n^n$, in this case $b_n^{a_n}$ converges to $0$.
3. $a_n=\frac1n$ and $b_n=2^n$, in which case $b_n^{a_n}=2$.

Comment: nice answerAsaf

Answer (score 1):

No. It depends on the rate at which something approaches $\infty$ and the rate at which the other something approaches $0$. For example,

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (e^{n})^{k/n}$ has indeterminate form $\infty^0$ However, the limit itself equals $e^k$. Therefore, by choosing your favorite constant, you just made $\infty^0$ "equal" any positive real number. This idea of rates is the only proper way to interpret $\infty^0$ since $\infty \not \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Whether an expression like $\infty^0$ is defined depends on the context in which you expect the expression to be meaningful.

In calculus, $\infty^0$ is not defined, because there is no way to extend the power function $\mathrm{pow}:(a,b)\mapsto a^b$ to these values continuously. This interpretation is given by Asaf Karagila and mlg4080.

If you're a calculus student, and you're asking in the context of calculus, then stop reading now. Below this line is forbidden knowledge.

---

In computer science, the designers of a language or other standard may choose to reserve $\infty^0$ as undefined behavior, or they may leave it as implementation-defined, or they may give it some definite value. If there is a definite value, it is typically $1$:

- In [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), [POSIX](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pow.3.html), and [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html), $a^0=1$ for all $a$, so in particular $\infty^0=1$.
- In [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), $a^0=1$ for all $a$ other than NaN, so in particular $\infty^0=1$.

In higher mathematics, there are some extended versions of arithmetic that define operations which are reminiscent of $\infty^0$. If $a$ is an infinite ordinal number, cardinal number, or hyperreal number, then $a^0=1$. This is sas' answer. But it is uncommon to write "$\infty$" in place of $a$, since there are many different infinite numbers in each arithmetic.